# Is this sentence using "Writing" and "Advertising" correct?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, nouns, gerunds

My intention is to explain that all writing (as an activity) is advertising (as an activity). Same goes for the second sentence.

Does this sentence convey an explanation mentioned above?

> All writing is advertising. Not all writing is a good advertising.

---

If I understand it correctly, both "Writing" and "Advertising" can be used either as a noun or a verb.

**Noun**

> My writing on health was a huge success.
>
> I saw a cool advertising on health.

... Is this a gerund? A verb that functions as a noun?

**Verb**

> I am writing
>
> Stop advertising yourself.

Comment: Yes, it sounds fine to me. Although "I saw a cool advertising" is not right, because it's an uncountable noun. So it should be "I saw some cool advertising".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is grammatically correct.  You are using the words as gerunds.

In this case it is slightly ambiguous because both both *writing* and *advertising* can refer to both the activity and the product of the activity. eg:

```
"There was some writing on the wall and some advertising on the side of the bus."
```

Your sentence could also be interpreted as meaning that all written material is advertising material.